# Assigning c and cpp files in the _SOURCE in Makefile.am

Tags: c++, c, makefile, autotools

My project contains c++ files and c files and I want to build my project with autotools.

So I create the `Makefile.am`. and I m wondering if it's possible to put both `cpp` files and `c` files together into the `_SOURCE` variable

```
myprogram_SOURCES = \
  file1.c   \
  file2.c   \
  file3.cpp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add C and C++ files to `_SOURCES`.

Comment: together and at the same time ?

Comment: Yes, just like you have it in your example.